# Who knows the android mediaplayer states by their int value in LogCat?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have an implementation that is using the Android MediaPlayer class. I keep on bumping into various bugs, change the code, bump into another bug. Depending on the bug, I get LogCat error messages reporting back from the MediaPlayer:

"*xyz* called in state *x*".

I don't want to post a thread for each bug I bump into, I rather get a hang of it all and fix the bugs myself. But I cannot find any document that would tell me **which state number maps to which state**, as they are described on the MediaPlayer online documentation.

Can someone post a link to such a list, or provide the list right here in this post? I think I would not be the only one that would appreciate that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are the states currently declared in [mediaplayer.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libmedia/include/media/mediaplayer.h) on the master branch of the AOSP:

```
enum media_player_states {
    MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR        = 0,
    MEDIA_PLAYER_IDLE               = 1 << 0,
    MEDIA_PLAYER_INITIALIZED        = 1 << 1,
    MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARING          = 1 << 2,
    MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED           = 1 << 3,
    MEDIA_PLAYER_STARTED            = 1 << 4,
    MEDIA_PLAYER_PAUSED             = 1 << 5,
    MEDIA_PLAYER_STOPPED            = 1 << 6,
    MEDIA_PLAYER_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE  = 1 << 7
};
```

Comment: Many thanks. How did you find the link? I googled like crazy. If there is a nice search function to browse the actual headers of the framework...it can't get any better than that. :-)

Comment: _"How did you find the link?"_ I used to work with customizing the Android audio framework for a living a few years ago.

Comment: Can you see how I'm bowing my head? :-D

Comment: Why is this not in the documentation if the error reporting uses it!? It would not be hard to add numbers to their potato quality state diagram.

Answer (score 8):

Building on Michael's answer, here are the declared states with decimal values added for each of the shifted bits. Yeah, they're trivial to calculate, but this saves the extra step when resolving LogCat messages.

```
enum media_player_states {
    MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR        = 0,        //   0
    MEDIA_PLAYER_IDLE               = 1 << 0,   //   1
    MEDIA_PLAYER_INITIALIZED        = 1 << 1,   //   2
    MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARING          = 1 << 2,   //   4
    MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED           = 1 << 3,   //   8
    MEDIA_PLAYER_STARTED            = 1 << 4,   //  16
    MEDIA_PLAYER_PAUSED             = 1 << 5,   //  32
    MEDIA_PLAYER_STOPPED            = 1 << 6,   //  64
    MEDIA_PLAYER_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE  = 1 << 7    // 128
};
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

For example

> public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_IO
>
> Added in API level 17 File or network related operation errors.
>
> Constant Value: -1004 (0xfffffc14)